# How can I use getElementById for a control created in code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I am trying to use the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event on a table td created on the client side, so that when the a user mouses over the table cell, a panel becomes visible, and when they mouse out, the panel becomes invisible.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onmouseover="ToggleVisibility('FileHeader', true);" onmouseout="ToggleVisibility('FileHeader', false);">
            Some content goes here.                         
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` call the following JavaScript function, also defined on the client side.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleVisibility(id, visible) {
        var content = document.getElementById(id);
        if (content != null) {
            if (visible) {
                content.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The "id" that I'm passing in to `getElementByID` is the id for a Panel control created in code behind during Page_Load.  The Panel is added to a different table that is defined on the client side like so:

```
<asp:Table ID="HelpTable" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

Here is the panel created and added to the table in code behind:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
HelpTable.Rows.Add(row);
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
row.Cells.Add(cell);

Panel pFileHeader = new Panel();
pFileHeader.ID = "FileHeader";
pFileHeader.Style.Add("Display", "none");

cell.Controls.Add(pFileHeader);
```

(The panel, `pFileHeader` contains actual content (labels with text, etc.) that I've left out for simplicity).

When this Panel is created on the client side, my `ToggleVisibility` function works fine, but when the Panel is created in code behind, `getElementById` returns null.  I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I understood your problem, since `getElementById returns null` there might be a problem/chance of delay in creation of Element. I'm not sure about this (just a guess). Any way I need to look into `Demo`.  Can u please post a link to ur page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net will automatically name mangle all of the id's of you runat=server objects.  You can retrieve the mangled ID using the clientId property.

Comment: Thank you! I'm now calling ToggleVisibility like this (after making pFileHeader public):
onmouseover="ToggleVisibility('<%=pFileHeader.ClientID%>', true);"

instead of like this:
onmouseover="ToggleVisibility('FileHeader', true);"

And it works perfectly!  I'm a little embarrassed that it was this easy, but Thank you!